# 3 decimal precision in Java

Tags: java

```
    Float x = 4;
    Float answer = 4/16;
```

The answer for this is `0.25`, but I want to display the answer upto **3 decimal places**, like `0.250`.

How to achieve that? Please help?

Comment: String.format("%.3f", answer)

Comment: *FYI:* That code doesn't compile.

Comment: **1)** `4/16` is zero (`0`) since both operands are integer, integer division is performed - at least one of the numbers must be float, e.g. `(float)4/16` or `4F/16`; **2)** since the result is an `int`, it cannot be assigned to `Float` (would work if it was a primitive (`float`))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have decimal precision, use `BigDecimal` class.
Number of decimal places can be specified in setScale as below

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("0.25");
a = a.setScale(3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
```

Comment: I recommend BigDecimal.

Comment: The question isn't to have decimal precision, it already has that, but to print the result with 3 fractional digits.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson :My answer is generic and not specific to 3 decimal places. Formatting it with formatter converts it to string and thus makes overburden while operating numbers. BigDecimal on other hand can be customized for given decimal places

Comment: I agree with @Joakim Danielson. It would be more appropriate if this would be a comment instead of an answer. I decide to flag it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson : I have updated my answer, can you recheck

Comment: `BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN` is deprecated as of Java 9, and we are currently at Java 13. Since `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN` has been around since Java 5, it's time to begin using it.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution is to use `toString()` cut off at the decimal point using `split(".")`. If the length of the resulting string is less than 3, add zeroes until the length is three. If it is greater than three, cut off there. Such as:

```java
public String triplePrecision(Float float) {

    String tmp = float.toString();
    int length = tmp.split(".")[1].length();//numbers after decimal

    for (int i = 0; i < 3 - length; i++) {

        tmp += "0"; //appending zeroes

    }

    return tmp.substring(0, indexOf(".") + 3); //start to 3 places after decimal

}
```

Comment: I wonder what happens with for example `0.249999`; (not to speak of an argument/variable called `float`)

Comment: not very good to have a `split` and an `indexOf`  for almost same reason , also I am pretty sure that `split(".")` does not do what you think it is - `.` means any character in regular expressions, you will end up with an empty array